# I want to add same html form when clicking add button in C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, methods, asp.net-core-mvc

how do i make a code for adding the same content of a page after clicking add button.

This is my html code and aspx.cs code what should i write in a  Nextbutton_click block to get the content on same page.

how to add a same form element below after clicking the add button in asp.net mvc

.aspx.cs

```
protected void submitbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                try
                {
                    int ID = Convert.ToInt32(Idbox.Text);
                    string Subject = Subjectname.Text;
                    string Question = question.Text;
                    string Option1 = option1.Text;
                    string Option2 = option2.Text;
                    string Option3 = option3.Text;
                    string Option4 = option4.Text;
                    string Correctans = correctans.Text;

                    string cs = "Data Source=LAPTOP-EIBDQABG;Initial Catalog=quiz;Integrated Security=True";
                    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);

                //already exist validation
                SqlCommand queryexistvalidation =new SqlCommand("select ID from Quizcreationtable where ID='"+ int.Parse(Idbox.Text)+ "'",con);
                SqlDataAdapter sd = new SqlDataAdapter(queryexistvalidation);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sd.Fill(dt);
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    Response.Write("<script>alert('ID already exist! please use different ID.');</script>");
                }

                else
                {

                    string query = string.Format("insert into Quizcreationtable values({0},'{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}')", ID, Subject, Question, Option1, Option2, Option3, Option4, Correctans);
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Response.Write("<script>alert('" + ex.Message + "');</script>");
                }
            
        }

        protected void Nextbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           
        }
    }
```

.aspx

```
        <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <p>creating quiz page.</p>
    <center>
        <div class="card-body1">
            <div class="row" id="quizcreation">
                <div class="col">

                    <div class="idbox">
                        <label class="idreq">Enter ID : </label>
                        <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" runat="server" ID="Idbox"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator style="color:red;" ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter ID" ControlToValidate="Idbox" validation-error-class="is-invalid" validation-valid-class="is-valid"> </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <label class="idreq">Subject name : </label>
                        <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" runat="server" ID="Subjectname"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator style="color:red;" ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Subject name is required" ControlToValidate="Subjectname" validation-error-class="is-invalid" validation-valid-class="is-valid"> </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </div><br />

                    <div>
                        <label class="idreq">Question : </label>
                        <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" runat="server" ID="question"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator style="color:red;" ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Question name is required" ControlToValidate="question" validation-error-class="is-invalid" validation-valid-class="is-valid"> </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="Options">

                <div class="option1">
                    <label class="op1">A)</label>
                    <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" runat="server" ID="option1"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator style="color:red;" ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter answer" ControlToValidate="option1" validation-error-class="is-invalid" validation-valid-class="is-valid"> </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </div>

                <div class="option2">
                    <label class="op1">B)</label>
                    <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" runat="server" ID="option2"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator style="color:red;" ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter answer" ControlToValidate="option2" validation-error-class="is-invalid" validation-valid-class="is-valid"> </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </div>

                <div class="option3">
                    <label class="op1">C)</label>
                    <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" runat="server" ID="option3"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator style="color:red;" ID="RequiredFieldValidator6" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter answer" ControlToValidate="option3" validation-error-class="is-invalid" validation-valid-class="is-valid"> </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </div>

                <div class="option4">
                    <label class="op1">D)</label>
                    <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" runat="server" ID="option4"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator style="color:red;" ID="RequiredFieldValidator7" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter answer" ControlToValidate="option4" validation-error-class="is-invalid" validation-valid-class="is-valid"> </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="answerdropdown">
                <label class="op1">Select correct answer : </label>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="correctans" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" runat="server" Style="background-color: white; color: black;">
                    <asp:ListItem Value=" ">--Correct Answer--</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>A</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>B</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>C</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>D</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList><br />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator style="color:red;" ID="RequiredFieldValidator8" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please select correct answer" ControlToValidate="correctans" validation-error-class="is-invalid" validation-valid-class="is-valid"> </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div class="controlbuttons">
                <div class="perviousbtn">
                    <asp:Button class="btn btn-secondary" ID="Perviousquestion" runat="server" Text="Pervious" />
                </div>
                <div class="submitbtn">
                    <asp:Button class="btn btn-success margin-auto" ID="submitbutton" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="submitbutton_Click" />
                </div>
                <div class="nextbtn">
                    <asp:Button class="btn btn-primary" ID="Nextbutton" runat="server" Text="Next" OnClick="Nextbutton_Click" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </center>
</asp:Content>
```

need a way to do that please help.

Comment: To dynamically add form elements in an ASP.NET Web Forms application, incorporate both client-side JavaScript and server-side C# code. Use JavaScript to clone existing form elements and append them when the "Add" button is clicked, and ensure this script runs in the browser. Then, add a button in your ASPX file that calls this JavaScript function.